# Similar function SwingUtilities.invokeLater in android?

Tags: java, android, swing

Sometime I feel that using AsyncTask is quite overkill for the task, I am looking for similar function like SwingUtilities.invokeLater in android. Because I just want to execute one line of code, no point to create a new class for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action);
```

The above method is slightly different than invokeLater of java because it checks if you are already on ui thread then it will run your Runnable immediately.

There is another way to make sure your Runnable gets called later and not immediately even if you are on UI thread. To do that you write following code while you are on the main thread.. if you call this when on backend thread your runnable will be exected on backend thread..

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your code..
    }
);
```

Comment: And how to transfer data to maintread?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember exactly what `invokeLater()` does, but if you want to execute something delayed, you can use [postDealayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29). That goes on the UI thread, so not fit for long running tasks, naturally.

Comment: `invokeLater()` puts a `Runnable` onto a queue so that it will be executed by the EDT.

Comment: postDelayed() is not static function? Then I have to carry the UI thread's handler all the time in order to call it?

Comment: @GregKopff where is the function located (in which class)?