# How to return a variable from a Runnable/Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-room

I want to run `playerDao.getPlayerList()` in a separate thread, and write the result to the `playerList` variable.

PlayerCreation.java:

```
//initialize variables to access player database
Player_Database playerDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), Player_Database.class, "players").build();
Player_DAO playerDao = playerDatabase.getPlayerDAO();

//initialize view that needs to be filled with player entries (every entry has an "edit player" and a "delete player" button)
LinearLayout playerListView = findViewById(R.id.playerList);

//THIS IS WHERE TROUBLE STARTS

//functions that access the database have to be run from a seperate thread so the UI doesn't get locked
Runnable playerListRunnable = () -> {
    List<Player> playerListFromThread = playerDao.getPlayerList();

    //TODO: return playerListFromThread, and use it to create a new ArrayList
};
Thread playerListThread = new Thread(playerListRunnable);
playerListThread.start();

ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>(playerListFromThread);

//THIS IS WHERE TROUBLE ENDS (I think...)

//fill view with entries
for (Player p : playerList) {
    //"loadPlayerEntry" inflates the entry, and adds it to the list
    loadPlayerEntry(p, playerListView);
}
```

For why I create a List<Player> then convert it to an ArrayList<Player> see the comment:

Player_DAO.java:

```
@Dao
public interface Player_DAO {

    @Insert
    void addPlayer(Player player);

    @Update
    void editPlayerName(Player player);

    @Query("DELETE FROM players WHERE name IS :name")
    void deletePlayer(String name);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY name")
    //using an ArrayList doesn't work. I tried. It complains.
    List<Player> getPlayerList();

}
```

Player_Database.java:

```
@Database(entities = {Player.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class Player_Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract Player_DAO getPlayerDAO();
}
```

Player.java:

```
@Entity(tableName = "players")
public class Player {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "player_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int player_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //TODO: store statistics here someday

    //Constructor
    public Player(String name){
        this.player_id = 0;
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Get-Methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getPlayer_id() {
        return player_id;
    }

    //Set-Methods
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setPlayer_id(int player_id) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
    }

}
```

To my understanding Room stores my Java Player Objects as rows in a database and allows to retrieve the data through the functions of a Database Access Object. Inconveniently (but understandably), this has to be done in a separate thread. `playerDao` gets my player list and the result is written to a variable inside the thread called `playerListFromThread`. This works but I can't manage to return `playerListFromThread` to the scope in PlayerCreation.java.

I tried creating a new Java file called playerListThread.java, but there were problems with Room's `databaseBuilder()` and `getApplication()` function. I tried setting up automatic list updates on database changes with the RxJava3 library, which is supported by Room.

I expected returning a value from a thread not to be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a database is not what locks your UI. What locks it is doing anything at all in a handler function that takes too much time. Starting a new thread to call `playerDao.getPlayerList()` and then *waiting for the thread to return a result* will take even *more* time than just calling the function.

The way out of this conundrum is to;

1. Start a new background thread to perform the long task,*
2. Update the UI to show the user that the long task is in progress, and then,
3. Immediately return. Don't wait for the task to finish.

Instead of waiting for a result from the task, what you want instead is for the background thread to post a new message to the UI thread after the task is finished.  The handler for the new message can then update the UI to show the result.

I don't know much about Android, but I've heard a rumor that *one* way for the background thread to post the second message is to have it call `Activity.runOnUiThread(...)` (See, [Similar function SwingUtilities.invokeLater in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11641670/801894))

---

* Actually, instead of creating a new thread, it's better still to use a *thread pool,* but that can be the topic of a whole other question. (A question that I won't answer because I don't know the preferred way to set up or use a thread pool in Android.)